# Mock Remote HTTP Response in Tests

Tags: javascript, http, testing, mocking, axios

I'm attempting to write a test that checks the behaviour of my app depending on the response received from an API. To do this, I'm trying to make the response to the request I make have the config that I need.

An example is checking to see that my app redirects to the home page after logging in. I need the response to be HTTP 200 and have any value for an API key.

I am using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to make the requests

Currently I have tried the following libraries with no success

- moxios
- axios-mock-adapter
- nock

Does anyone have any experience with mocking remote HTTP requests and their responses?

EDIT: If it helps, I am using Mocha and Chai for tests

```
it('Does stuff', function () {
  moxios.stubRequest('/auth/get_api_key', {
    status: 200,
    responseText: 'hello'
  })
  return this.app.client.setValue('[name="username"]', 'testing').then(() => {
    return this.app.client.setValue('[name="password"]', 'testing').then(() => {
      return this.app.client.submitForm('#login-form').then(() => {
        return this.app.client.getRenderProcessLogs().then(function (logs) {
          console.log(logs)
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

The code above is what I'm using to see if the request goes through and it outputs this

> [ { level: 'SEVERE',
>       message: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/get_api_key/ - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED',
>       source: 'network',
>       timestamp: 1510082077495 } ]

Answer (score 0):

My example was mostly taken from the [moxios docs](https://github.com/axios/moxios).

First in your test import the libraries you need. Afterwards, you'll handle creating and destroying the mock axios server in your `beforeEach` and `afterEach` hooks. You'll then pass a `sinon.spy()` into axios' get request you want to spy on.

This get request will be mocked by moxios and you can access it through `moxios.wait(() => { moxios.request.mostRecent(); });` Inside the `wait()` method you can set the response you want on the most recent requests.

Afterwards, just like when you use axios you'll use the `then()` function to get your response. Inside the `then()` you can create your tests for that specific response. When you're done with your specs call `done();` to close the request and move the specs along.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import moxios from 'moxios';
import sinon from 'sinon'; 
import { equal } from 'assert';  //use the testing framework of your choice

beforeEach(() => {
  moxios.install();
});

afterEach(() => {
  moxios.uninstall();
});

it('Does stuff', (done) => {
  moxios.withMock(() => {
    let onFulfilled = sinon.spy();
    axios.get('/auth/get_api_key').then(onFulfilled);
    moxios.wait(() => {
      let request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
      request.respondWith({
        status: 200,
        response: {
          apiKey: 1234567890
        }
      }).then((res) => {
        equal(onFulfilled.called, true);
        equal(res.status, 200);
        equal(res.response.apiKey, 1234567890);
        done();
      })
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. One thing to note is that I had to do `equal(res.data.apiKey, 1234567890);` to get the example to work.

In addition, this doesn't seem to fit my case unfortunately. I do not have access to the axios instance used by the app. I am not testing that the api returns the correct values, I want to test that the app sets the correct value from the api. 

In other words, I am making the request in the app, and can't do it manually in the test. I am wanting to respond to the request the app makes so that is sets the apiKey value correctly. Does that make sense?

Comment: After some more investigation it seems that it is meant to mock those other requests by default. As is demonstrated in their docs. But for some reason, moxios.requests.mostRecent() is returning undefined

Comment: Are you calling an axios instance and hitting the test endpoint in your specs? I'm referring to this line here `axios.get('/auth/get_api_key').then(onFulfilled);` Also worth ruling out, do you have all the right dependencies installed (sinon, axios, moxios)?